# How to use more than 64 remote options for a random-remote openvpn connection

Tags: openvpn

I have a great list of servers that I would like to tunnel through, which would be selected randomly through the "random-remote" feature, however when I try to use my config with the servers added, I get an Options error, "Maximum number of remote options (64) exceeded". I see no real reason why this has a hard limit, and so, how can one bypass it?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! The `remote-random` option is described in OpenVPN's documentation as "a kind of basic load-balancing measure". Thus, 64 should be plenty. As far as why they chose 64, instead of 32 or 256, or for possible workarounds, you might try asking the OpenVPN support community -- see https://openvpn.net/community/.

Comment: And, it's open source. So you could change the `#define CONNECTION_LIST_SIZE 64` line in `options.h` to `#define CONNECTION_LIST_SIZE 256`, compile, and see if that breaks anything.

Comment: @DougDeden I am not the most confident with c++, so please bear with me if I miss something obvious here. I am looking through the repo and I find these files of interest, https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/44725ad0942029b45cc8168ce8f26ec47da02378/openvpn/client/cliopt.hpp https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/master/openvpn/client/remotelist.hpp , but I can't see options_error() being raised in relation to the size of the input. Can you see anything here?

Comment: I also am not a C programmer, but I downloaded the source from https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/. In src\OpenVPN\options.h, I find the definition of CONNECTION_LIST_SIZE. And in options.c, I find the code that raises the "Maximum number of …" error.